# Nested fragments no view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-nested-fragment

I am working on simple application having nested fragments with tab layout. Parent activity is LandingActivity. Inside of the LandingActivity i am calling LandingFragment. Inside of the LandingFragment i have following functionlity.

```
Tasks TAB Fragments flow is TasksMainFragment->TasksFragment->DetailFragment.

Pending TAB Fragments flow is PendingMainFragment->PendingFragment->PendingDetailFragment
```

The following code represents calling TasksFragment from TasksMainFragment.

```
TasksFragment fragment=new TasksFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.id_frame, fragment, "tasks");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tasks");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Below code represents calling DetailFragment from TasksFragment. Basically TasksFragment contains recyclerview with some tasks. When user tap on the task it will open the DetailFragment of the task.

```
Fragment fragment = new DetailFragment();

        FragmentManager manager = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        ItemModel item = list.get(position);
        bundle.putSerializable("item", item);
        bundle.putBoolean("having", havingStartedService());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_frame, fragment, "details");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("details");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

When the user switch to pending tab same behaviour or same functionality will work. But the problem is when i open application after some time or open application first time on morning everyday i am facing this problem.

Other scenario when i change the screen orientation also i am facing this problem.

I am posting logcat below for better understanding.

```
12-20 16:33:01.658 21590-21590/com.naushad.kenostaff E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.naushad.kenostaff, PID: 21590
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naushad.kenostaff/com.naushad.kenostaff.landing.LandingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070059 (com.naushad.kenostaff:id/id_frame) for fragment TasksFragment{b980f0d #7 id=0x7f070059 tasks}
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4556)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070059 (com.naushad.kenostaff:id/id_frame) for fragment TasksFragment{b980f0d #7 id=0x7f070059 tasks}
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
                                                                           at com.stfalcon.androidmvvmhelper.mvvm.activities.BindingActivity.onStart(BindingActivity.java:50)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6701)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4556) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

please give me some help on this issue. I am facing this problem from past 1 week, i tried so many ways but nothing is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "No view found for id" Are you using Single Activity as parent or not ?

Comment: Yes i am using single activity as parent

Answer (score 2):

By using **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()**.i resolved both crashes.

For Opening TasksFragment i am using below code.

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();`

For opening DetailFragment i am using below code.

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();`
in tasks tab. In pending tab also i am following same way to resolve crashes.

Now i am facing other issue. I am checking which fragment is visible to the user in both TasksMainFragment and PendingMainFragment. Because i am opening two fragments in both main fragments. So depends upon that i want to update UI of the visible fragment.

By using below code i am checking which fragment is visible to the user.

```
    Fragment f1 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.id_frame);
if (f1 instanceof TasksFragment) {
                Log.d("", "GCM Receiverf1task:Tasks");
//                ((TasksFragment) f1).updateUI(message, order);
            }
            else if (f1 instanceof DetailFragment) {
                Log.d("", "GCM Receiverf1task:Tasks Details");
//                if(message.contains("Started") || message.contains("Completed") || message.contains("cancelled"))
//                    ((DetailFragment) f1).updateUI(message, order);
            }
```

But when i am in TasksFragment the above code is not working. When i am in DetailFragment above code is working fine. Please help me to resolve this issue or let me know if anything wrong in my way.

Comment: I resolved issues by using above answer but facing with other issue getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager(); on a null object reference.